# Mathematica can not solve a symbolic matrix equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use mathematica to solve a matrix equation, and i wrote the following code:

```
ClearAll

PAII = {{xx, yy, zz, ww}} // MatrixForm
PAII = Transpose[PAII] // MatrixForm
SMatrix = {{p - 1, q, 0, 0}, {p, -1, q, 0}, {0, p, -1, q}, {0, 0, p, q - 1}} // MatrixForm
PAII.SMatrix // MatrixForm
Solve[PAII.SMatrix = PAII, {xx, yy, zz, ww}] // MatrixForm
```

varibles `PAII = {{xx yy zz ww}}` are what i want to solve

equation is `PAII.SMatrix = PAII`

And it shows the following errors:

[image]

It seems that the Transpose and dot product function does not work.

I do not know how to solve this problem. Asking for ur help!

I tried to write the matrix with actual values, and it does not show errors.

Answer (score 0):

`MatrixForm` makes  a result that is pretty to look at, but cannot be used in calculations. It is possible to use `()` to show your pretty result and still be able to use the actual values for calculations

Mathematica internally handles some row versus column vectors.

Use `==` and not `=` inside equations that are given to `Solve`

Try

```
(PAII = {xx, yy, zz, ww})//MatrixForm
(PAII = Transpose[PAII])//MatrixForm
(SMatrix = {{p-1,q,0,0},{p,-1,q,0},{0,p,-1,q},{0,0,p,q-1}})//MatrixForm
(PAII.SMatrix)//MatrixForm
(Solve[PAII.SMatrix == PAII, {xx, yy, zz, ww}])//MatrixForm
```

which returns the solution

```
{{xx -> 0, yy -> 0, zz -> 0, ww -> 0}}
```

and see if that provides the solution that you want.